# LIKE not working mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The below query doesn't return any result,

```
   $title = urldecode($_GET['dc']);//contains Speakers
   $r = '%'.$title.'%';
   $stmt = $mydb->prepare(" SELECT * from table where title LIKE ?");
   echo $mydb->error;
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $r );
   $stmt->execute();
```

but if I change the `$r` to `'%'.'Speak'.'%';` it works

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what does `$title` contain? What's the error?

Comment: `//contains 'Speakers'` do you mean with the quotes?

Comment: @mario removed the quotes.

Comment: What is the exact title that is being returned once you change $r ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you don't need `urldecode`. Remove it, as it may wreck your title.

Secondly, beware that depending on your collate, your Like might be case-sensitive.

Third... You say `$_GET['dc']` contains 'Speakers'. Are you sure? Did you try doing `echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['dc']);` to be sure?

Lastly... Later you say it works, when you use `Speak` ... not `Speakers` ... Which is it? It off course matters if you search with `%Speakers%` or `%Speak%`.

**edit** Also try trimming your title to remove leading and trailing spaces. So try changing `$title = urldecode($_GET['dc']);` into `$title = trim($_GET['dc']);`

Comment: I need urldecode because I am encoding the url on the first page. 2nd I echoed and got `speakers` so yeah it contains speakers. It should work both ways, `speak` or `speakers` because it is a `LIKE` If I need the exact `Speakers` then why would I use `LIKE` instead of just using `=`?

Comment: Just remove `urldecode` on this second page. Your webserver and PHP already do the decoding for you. (Don't remove `urlencode` on the first page, there it should stay!) 2nd, ok, great, so $_GET works. Did you get the first letter in capital or lower case? ... Third ... `%Speak%` will find you the words `Speaks` or `Speaking` for example.... But `%Speakers%` won't.

Comment: By the way, you may also want to trim the title. So try changin `$title = urldecode($_GET['dc']);` into `$title = trim($_GET['dc']);` This way leading or trailing spaces will be removed.

Comment: I removed the urldecode and nothing has changed however I found a mistake on my first page in which I had extra `&`. Also `'%'.'speakers'.'%'` works and should work. Thanks you gave me some tips.